# Is the 90 days visa-waiver for the entire trip or for each country?

Tags: visas, schengen, us-citizens, visas-on-arrival

Suppose I fly to France and stay for 90 days. Then I cross into Spain by land, then fly to the Netherlands, then go to Norway. So the total trip length is much longer than 90 days. As long as I stay less than 90 days in each country individually, can I just take my American passport and not worry about anything? Or do I have to do some paperwork?

Answer (score 3):

Basically you can stay 90 days out of each 180 days in the whole of the Schengen area. That is no more than 90 days for all the countries you mention.
There is almost no way to extend that when your whole stay is within the Schengen area.

You may have to adjust your travel plans or look for the very few loopholes that do exist.

The UK is not part of the Schengen area, nor is Ireland, which may give you alternative destinations to reduce your time in the Schengen area.

Comment: Ok, then I'm good, my trip overall is less than 180 days. Could you give me a link explaining this?

Comment: Based on your question, you are not good, look at the question they give the link for, when this is called a duplicate.

Comment: @RenéG There are some countries where Americans can stay for up to 90 days even if they've already exhausted their 90-day stay in the Schengen area.  But you would have to *leave* the Schengen area *through one of these countries.*  I am fairly sure that Spain, the Netherlands, and Norway are not among them.  If I am right about that, and you spent 90 days in France, you will not be able to avoid an overstay by traveling to any of those countries.

Comment: @Willeke based on another question by the same person, the person is actually a dual US/Polish citizen, so the 90/180 rule is actually completely irrelevant.

Comment: @phoog, no mention of any EU passport in the question and there is a clear mention of "can I just take my American passport" which I based my answer on.

Comment: @Willeke absolutely.  Given the information in the question, everything in your answer is correct.